# Getting First Row Repeated value in whole list Count list in View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

[MY SQl output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDnWo.jpg)
[MY Output View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g10X6.jpg)  Both are Different

The same query when fire in MS server Sql is proper value .
Row Count is same but only First row is repeated in LINQ ....
no error , no idea !

```
Table("SalarySlip")]
    public class Document
    {
        [Key]
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        
        public string Basic { get; set; }
        public string Bonus { get; set; }
        public string Flexi { get; set; }
        public string HRA { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public string NetPay { get; set; }
        public string OtherDeduction { get; set; }
        public string PF { get; set; }
        public string Special { get; set; }
        public string TDS { get; set; }
        public string TotalDeduction { get; set; }
        public string TotalEarning { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
       }
        

public ActionResult EmpSalaryHistory(string EmployeeID )
{
    
    DatabaseContext _context = new DatabaseContext();
    var Userdata = _context.SalarySlip.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == EmployeeID).OrderByDescending(x => x.Month).ToList();


    if (Userdata.Count != 0)
    {
        TempData["data"] = EmployeeID;
        return View(Userdata);
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["data"] = EmployeeID;
        //return View();
        return RedirectToAction("Demo");
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you are using **FirstOrDefault()** which is returning only the first item from the table that match the criteria

Comment: DatabaseContext _context = new DatabaseContext();
            var Userdata = _context.SalarySlip.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == EmployeeID).OrderByDescending(x => x.Month).ToList();


            if (Userdata.Count != 0)
            {
               
                return View(Userdata);
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["data"] = Userdata;
                //return View();
                return RedirectToAction("Demo");
            }

Comment: what about this ?

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: yes but same response

Comment: If you changed the code, it couldn't be the same response. Please update your question with your current code and results.

Comment: @NetMage pls see the updated question with same o/p .

Comment: You should inspect the value of `UserData` this looks like your rendering code might be at fault, not the query.

Comment: yes userdata contains all list value same as First Row no idea why , tried with all combinations queries..